# Addressing many-to-many relationship through my endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a RESTful API that I can currently use to add widgets and optional categories. My intent is to make this a many-to-many relationship between widgets and categories. I think I'm close but I'm getting an error if I try to assign a widget to a category; I want to be able to also assign a category to a widget. This is what I have so far:

In my models:

```
class Widget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    widget = models.ManyToManyField(Widget)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

# TODO: add many-to-many relationship between widget and category
class WidgetCategory(models.Model):
    widget = models.ForeignKey(Widget, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.id)
```

In my serializer:

```
class WidgetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Widget
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'date_created', 'date_modified')

class WidgetCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WidgetCategory
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'widget', 'category', 'date_created', 'date_modified')

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    widgetcategory = WidgetCategorySerializer(source="*", many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
```

In my views:

```
class WidgetCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

class WidgetDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer

class CategoryCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

class CategoryDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

In my endpoint mappings:

```
url(r'^widgets/$', WidgetCreateView.as_view(), name="widget_create"),
url(r'^finishes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/widgets/$', WidgetCreateView.as_view(), name="widget_create"),
url(r'^sizes/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/widgets/$', WidgetCreateView.as_view(), name="widget_create"),
url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/widgets/$', WidgetCreateView.as_view(), name="widget_create"),
url(r'^widgets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        WidgetDetailsView.as_view(), name="widget_details"),

url(r'^categories/$', CategoryCreateView.as_view(), name="category_create"),
url(r'^widgets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/categories/$', CategoryCreateView.as_view(), name="category_create"),
url(r'^categories/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        CategoryDetailsView.as_view(), name="category_details"),
```

And when I try to add a new category and assign a widget to the new POST, I get this error:

```
TypeError at /categories/
'Category' object is not iterable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/categories/
Django Version: 2.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Category' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\joe_t\workspace\python_projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in to_representation, line 683
Python Executable:  C:\Users\joe_t\workspace\python_projects\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\widget_challenge',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files\\python\\36\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files\\python\\36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\joe_t\\workspace\\python_projects\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 21 Apr 2018 20:11:16 +0000
```

I don't understand what that error means; I'm still looking around online to get a clue. Has anyone seen this before and maybe have an idea as to how to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to get the complete stacktrace of this error?

Comment: I do have it but it's too large to paste in as a response.

Comment: `Internal Server Error: /categories/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joe_t\workspace\python_projects\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)`
...
`File "C:\Users\joe_t\workspace\python_projects\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable`

Comment: You can edit your answer and add it as a code block. They are scrollable so it should be fine unless the trace is incredibly long.

Answer (score 0):

@goterpsgo Looks like the `ListSerializer` class is being triggered for a `to_representation` call. How does `source="*"` work? I am not aware of this usage.

Can you try changing it to:
`widgetcategory = WidgetCategorySerializer(source="widget", many=True, read_only=True)`